# Korean characters fall apart in Dartpad

Tags: dart, utf-8

Korean characters fall apart when I use Dartpad
'가나다' shows as 'ㄱㅏㄴㅏㄷㅏ'

I use ipad with a bluetooth keyboard. They don't seem to be causing the problem here because it works fine on other websites. The characters only fall apart in Dartpad. Has anyone experienced similar problems?

I tried disconnecting the keyboard (also deleted it from the previous list of devices connected to the ipad)
Also tried switching off various options regarding the keyboard (CapsLock language toggle option)

Comment: You would probably be better served by opening an issue on the [github repo for dart pad](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/issues).

Comment: See [Unicode Normalization Forms](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/). `가나다` is NFC / NFKC (`\uac00\ub098\ub2e4`) while `ㄱㅏㄴㅏㄷㅏ` is  NFD / NFKD (`\u1100\u1161\u1102\u1161\u1103\u1161`)…